# determine some stats with tsql

Tags: t-sql

I have documents which can belong to several classes and can contain several tokens (words):

```
create table Tokens (
        Id INT not null,
       Text NVARCHAR(255) null,
       primary key (Id)
    )

create table DocumentClassTokens (
        Id INT not null,
       DocumentFk INT null,
       ClassFk INT null,
       TokenFk INT null,
       primary key (Id)
    )
```

I would like to determine these stats (for all tokens given the class):

- A = number of distinct documents which contain token and belong to class
- B = number of distinct documents which contain token and do not belong to class
- C = number of distinct documents which do not contain token and belong to class
- D = number of distinct documents which do not contain token and do not belong to class

I am using this at the moment but it does not look right (I am pretty sure that the computation of A and B is correct):

```
declare @class int;

select @class = id from dbo.Classes where text = 'bla'

;with A as
(
    select
        a.text as token,
        count(distinct DocumentFk) as A
    from dbo.Tokens as a
    inner join dbo.DocumentClassTokens as b on a.id = b.TokenFk and b.ClassFk = @class
    group by a.text
)
,B as
(
    select
        a.text as token,
        count(distinct DocumentFk) as B
    from dbo.Tokens as a
    inner join dbo.DocumentClassTokens as b on a.id = b.TokenFk and b.ClassFk != @class
    group by a.text
)
,C as
(
    select
        a.text as token,
        count(distinct DocumentFk) as C
    from dbo.Tokens as a
    inner join dbo.DocumentClassTokens as b on a.id != b.TokenFk and b.ClassFk = @class
    group by a.text
)
,D as
(
    select
        a.text as token,
        count(distinct DocumentFk) as D
    from dbo.Tokens as a
    inner join dbo.DocumentClassTokens as b on a.id != b.TokenFk and b.ClassFk != @class
    group by a.text
)
select 
    case when A is null then 0 else A end as A,
    case when B is null then 0 else B end as B,
    case when C is null then 0 else C end as C,
    case when D is null then 0 else D end as D,
    t.Text,
    t.id
from dbo.Tokens as t
left outer join A as a on t.text = a.token
left outer join B as b on t.text = b.token
left outer join C as c on t.text = c.token
left outer join D as d on t.text = d.token
order by t.text
```

Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Many thanks!

Best wishes,

Christian

PS:

Some test data:

```
use play;

drop table tokens
create table Tokens 
(
   Id INT not null,
   Text NVARCHAR(255) null,
   primary key (Id)
)

insert into Tokens (id, text) values (1,'1')
insert into Tokens (id, text) values (2,'2')

drop table DocumentClassTokens
create table DocumentClassTokens (
        Id INT not null,
       DocumentFk INT null,
       ClassFk INT null,
       TokenFk INT null,
       primary key (Id)
    )

insert into DocumentClassTokens (Id,documentfk,ClassFk,TokenFk) values (1,1,1,1) 
insert into DocumentClassTokens (Id,documentfk,ClassFk,TokenFk) values (2,1,1,2) 
insert into DocumentClassTokens (Id,documentfk,ClassFk,TokenFk) values (3,2,1,1) 
insert into DocumentClassTokens (Id,documentfk,ClassFk,TokenFk) values (4,2,2,1) 
insert into DocumentClassTokens (Id,documentfk,ClassFk,TokenFk) values (5,3,2,1) 
insert into DocumentClassTokens (Id,documentfk,ClassFk,TokenFk) values (6,3,2,3)
```

Comment: In your description you are talking about documents that contain or do not contain a (certain?) token and belong or do not belong to a (again, certain?) class. Now, in the script you've presented us you have definitely declared the `@class` parameter and so it is definitely a *certain* class that is going to be compared with. Following your description, there should also be declared a `@token` parameter in your script, shouldn't there? Or did you mean 'contain *tokens* ' (i.e. any tokens at all?). Please clarify what it should actually be.

Comment: @ Andriy M Thanks for the reply. The script should return a table with four columns token, A, B, C, D. So I would like to obtain the stats for all tokens given the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems now much clearer, and if I haven't overlooked anything, then here's a query you might try to run against your data.

```
DECLARE @class int;
SET @class = 1;

SELECT
  TokenFk,
  TokenClassDocs                        AS A,
  TokenNonClassDocs                     AS B,
  TotalClassDocs    - TokenClassDocs    AS C,
  TotalNonClassDocs - TokenNonClassDocs AS D
FROM (
  SELECT
    TokenFk,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE ClassFk WHEN @class THEN DocumentFk ELSE NULL END) AS TokenClassDocs,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE ClassFk WHEN @class THEN NULL ELSE DocumentFk END) AS TokenNonClassDocs
  FROM DocumentClassTokens dct
  GROUP BY dct.TokenFk
) AS bytoken
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT CASE ClassFk WHEN @class THEN DocumentFk ELSE NULL END) AS TotalClassDocs,
      COUNT(DISTINCT CASE ClassFk WHEN @class THEN NULL ELSE DocumentFk END) AS TotalNonClassDocs
    FROM DocumentClassTokens
  ) AS totals
```

Please let us know if it's all right.

---

**EDIT**

The above solution is wrong. Here's the fixed one, and it certainly seems correct only I do not like it as much as the wrong version (what an irony...).

```
DECLARE @class int;
SET @class = 1;

SELECT
  TokenFk,
  TokenClassDocs                        AS A,
  TokenNonClassDocs                     AS B,
  TotalClassDocs    - TokenClassDocs    AS C,
  TotalNonClassDocs - TokenNonClassDocs AS D
FROM (
  SELECT
    TokenFk,
    COUNT(DISTINCT cls.DocumentFk) AS TokenClassDocs,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN cls.DocumentFk IS NULL THEN dct.DocumentFk END) AS TokenNonClassDocs
  FROM DocumentClassTokens dct
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT DocumentFk
      FROM DocumentClassTokens
      WHERE ClassFk = @class
    ) cls ON dct.DocumentFk = cls.DocumentFk
  GROUP BY dct.TokenFk
) AS bytoken
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT cls.DocumentFk) AS TotalClassDocs,
      COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN cls.DocumentFk IS NULL THEN dct.DocumentFk END) AS TotalNonClassDocs
    FROM DocumentClassTokens dct
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT DocumentFk
        FROM DocumentClassTokens
        WHERE ClassFk = @class
      ) cls ON dct.DocumentFk = cls.DocumentFk
  ) AS totals
```

Note: I think I can see now how you can check if the figures are wrong: the sum of A, B, C, D in every row (i.e. for every token) must be equal to the total document count, which should not be surprising, because every document can satisfy 1 and only 1 of the 4 cases being explored. If the row sum is different from the total document count then some figures in the row are certainly wrong.

Comment: Thanks will have a look at it Monday.

Comment: Sorry there is something wrong. I just tested it on a test database which contains 3 documents and 2 tokens. It responds with 3 rows (there should only be 2 rows as there are only 2 tokens).

Comment: @csetzkorn: Would it be too much if I asked you to post your sample data here and the result produced?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong there are 3 tokens so the number of rows is correct. Please refer to PS for the correct answer for class 1 and token 2

Comment: @csetzkorn: I see now. But while checking my solution I also found out that yours is not entirely correct either. That is, if it fits you, fine, but otherwise it seems incorrect. Consider the example table `DocumentClassTokens` you've posted. There are 3 documents there, and we are analysing the stats for class 1 and token 2. More specifically, we are looking at the *documents* with neither class 1 nor token 2, it's your `D` value. Now, how many are they? Doc 1 has both, Doc 2 has class 1, these must not count. And only doc 3 has neither class 1 nor token 2, so D=1. And your scipt gives D=2.

Comment: @csetzkorn: I can see how your solution can be fixed, but as for mine, I'm still working on it. The present one is certainly incorrect, I admit.

Comment: Thanks I am getting confused myself now. But you are certainly right w.r.t. the D stats. Basically these stats are used to compute a chi square value for each token and class to eventually perform feature selection.

Comment: @csetzkorn: Posted a fix. Please take a look if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This seams to do what you want by your description. Looking at your code, I'm not so sure.

**Edit 1** With columns instead of rows and @ClassID as filter.

```
declare @ClassID int
set @ClassID = 1

;with cte(DokumentFk, TokenFk, ClassFk) as
(
  select DocumentFk, max(TokenFK), max(ClassFk) 
  from DocumentClassTokens
  where ClassFK = @ClassID
  group by DocumentFK
)
select
(select count(*)
 from cte
 where
   TokenFk is not null and
   ClassFk is not null) as A,
(select count(*)
 from cte
 where
   TokenFk is not null and
   ClassFk is null) as B,
(select count(*)
 from cte
 where
   TokenFk is null and
   ClassFk is not null) as C,
(select count(*)
 from cte
 where
   TokenFk is null and
   ClassFk is null) as D
```

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: AFAIK, an aggregate always returns a value. You should probably replace the NULL checks with zero comparisons. (I haven't yet analysed the script's logic, though.)

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: I stand corrected. If the aggregated column has all NULLs, then of course `MAX` should return NULL as well. That's the subtlety you have when using aggregates *with grouping*. Sorry, and I'm leaving both of my comments for somebody else's edification.

Comment: Tell me what is wrong? What do you except? Can you add some sample data and what result you want with that data?

Comment: The script should return a table with four columns token, A, B, C, D. So I would like to obtain the stats for all tokens given the class.

Comment: Ok. Added a version with columns instead of rows. I'm not sure about the @ClassID filter. That means that column B and D will always be 0, or...?

Comment: see my ps. the intersect version works fine and i now think my code too.

Comment: Good that it works for you. I understand now where I misunderstood your question. You want to count against two input parameters `@ClassID` and `@TokenID`. I thought that "do not contain token" meant you wanted to count documents not connected to any token. Therefore I counted null values.